# bootstrap navbar blinking when not collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/C0SgQdhpUhLTfoBQKDWu?p=preview)

The bootstrap navbar menu does not collapse on small screens by default if you click on a menu item.

I added `data-toggle="collapse"` and `data-target="#navbar-collapse"` to every menu item, so that the menu will collapse when menu items are selected.

So far so good, but I noticed that there's blinking even if the screen size is large, and the navbar items are not in the sandwich menu. I guess it's the collapse animation.

My question is is there any way to prevent this blinking/disable the animation with CSS? I know I could probably kill the animation with jQuery, but I'd rather avoid that as the whole application is built in Angular, and I think this is not a rare use case.

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully this isn't redundant to code you already have, but you didn't mention it so I'll assume you don't have it.

Have your main div you're holding the whole thing in be `navbar navbar-default` then put a `container-fluid` div inside that, and put this in right after:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navBodyId" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Page Title</a>
</div>
```

Then you can have your navbar like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navBodyId">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

and then close those 2 things I mentioned at the top.

You shouldn't have to collapse every part of the menu. Hopefully this helps, if not, the Bootstrap website is a really good resource, they have a bunch of examples with source code right below, but I'm sure you know that.

Comment: If you check out my Plunkr, you'll see that I used the same structure for the navbar as you suggested. I didn't want to post my HTML code, as it's 57 lines long. Sorry, but your answer is not answering my question.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see that you had that link at the top